# Определение типа файла

Tags: c++, c, macos, файлы

Здравствуйте, форумчане!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно программно определить тип файла. Пишу программу на С++, открываю директорию и смотрю, какие там файлы есть, получаю их имена, размеры. А в конце хотелось бы с помощью какой-либо функции определить тип файла, например, TXT или PDF. Программа под MAC OS. Помогите, плз!!!

Comment: Наверное, проще всего использовать утилиту `find`, например, вызвать  ее через `popen()` и проанализировать ее вывод (одну строку).

Comment: @avp, это, случайно, не на питоне решение?

Comment: Нет, я имел в виду C. Что-то в таком духе:

     char str[PATH_MAX * 2]; // должно хватить
     snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "file %s", filename);
     FILE *f = popen(str, "r");
     if (f) {
       fgets(str, sizeof(str), f);
       pclose(f);
       // тут разбор str
     } else
       fatal("file");

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю, как в macos, но в никсах вообще используется утилита file ибо расширение в unix-подобных системах ни о чем не говорит еще.

Так что гугли утилиту file.

Comment: @deterok, спасибо. Попробовала утилиту в терминале - выводит такой результат: ASCII text, with no line terminators, и это правда. Но хотелось бы, может, цыферку получить, которая означает определённый тип файла или константу какую-нибудь.

Comment: результат вывода -- строка. Можешь использовать как константу.

Comment: @Kristya
Можешь такую команду заюзать:

file --brief --mime-type <filename>

Вернет mime тип только, его уже храни в виде константы (спиок типов легко гуглиться, например вот http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)